# Is there any option to disable playground when in production mode?

Tags: apollo, apollo-server, fastify

Is there any option in apollo v3 to disable playground when inside production mode?
in v2 you could disable it by passing `playground: false` to ApolloServer options but can't find any in v3.

Im using apollo-server-fastify.

Edit: I have disabled playground but I still can access localhost:4000/graphql and get this message:

```
GET query missing.
```

my code:

```
const app = fastify({ trustProxy: true });
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  context: ({ request }: { request: FastifyRequest }) => {
    const auth = request.headers.authorization || "";
    return {
      auth,
      session: request.session,
      sessionStore: request.sessionStore,
    };
  },
  plugins: [
    myPlugin,
    env === "production"
      ? ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled()
      : ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(),
  ],
});
const corsOptions = {
  origin: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  credentials: true,
};
app.register(fastifyCookie);
app.register(fastifySession, {
  secret:
    "secreet",
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookieName: "GraphSSid",
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 * 7,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: true,
  },
});
existsSync(path.join(__dirname, "../files")) ||
  mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "../files"));
existsSync(path.join(__dirname, "../templates")) ||
  mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "../templates"));
existsSync(path.join(__dirname, "../logs")) ||
  mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "../logs"));

app.register(fastifyStatic, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "../files"),
  prefix: "/files",
});
app.register(fastifyStatic, {
  root: path.join(__dirname, "../templates"),
  prefix: "/templates",
  decorateReply: false, // the reply decorator has been added by the first plugin registration
});
app.addContentTypeParser("multipart", (request: any, payload, done) => {
  request.isMultipart = true;
  done(null);
});
app.addHook("preValidation", async function (request: any, reply) {
  if (!request.isMultipart) {
    return;
  }

  request.body = await processRequest(request.raw, reply.raw);
});
app.get("/api/update-product-available-inv", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await saveAvailable();
    console.log("success");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return "Success";
}); 
if (env === "production") {
  app.register(async (instance, opts, next) => {
    instance.register(fastifyStatic, {
      root: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
      prefix: "/",
    });
    instance.setNotFoundHandler((req, res) => {
      res.sendFile("index.html", path.join(__dirname, "build"));
    });
    next();
  });
}
server.start().then(() => {
  app.register(server.createHandler({ path: "/graphql", cors: corsOptions }));
  app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Server is ready at port 4000");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Apollo Server 3, Playground is disabled by default. In fact, they rolled their own "playground" because [Playground has been retired](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-playground/issues/1143). It instead has a "Landing Page".

So to answer your question, turning it off in production isn't really a thing anymore.

To answer what I assume will be your next question, here is the code to bring Playground back in "not-production":

```js
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground,
         ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled } from 'apollo-server-core';
new ApolloServer({
  plugins: [
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled()
      : ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(),
  ],
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But i still can access the localhost:4000/graphql and getting cannot get.

Comment: If you're getting "Cannot GET", then the plugins likely aren't set up correctly

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I would `console.log(env)`. If this is apollo-server@3, and you're getting that message instead of the new "Apollo Landing Page", you're properly registering the `ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled` plugin. Based on that code (and those assumptions) alone, I'm guessing your `env` is set as `production`.

Comment: Yes my env is production, is there any option to show my website instead of get query missing?

Comment: I assume `localhost:4000` is your website and `localhost:4000/graphql` is the GraphQL API where you're getting "GET query missing".

Comment: Yes is there any option to redirect the get query missing?

Comment: If you're hitting the GraphQL endpoint and you want to show the Apollo Landing page (or GraphQL Playground), you need to be running in non-production mode or find another way to include one of those plugins. What you are seeing is the expected output when you're in Production Mode. "Expected" here means both based on this code, and based on best practices. There should be no redirect from the GraphQL endpoint to any other place.