# Fetch graphQL query response bypass graphQL playground in the browser

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am using graphql apollo server and i have some queries and path is like:

**http://localhost:4000/demo**

after it redirects to that apollo playground and I can test my queries there

Now I am trying to fetching data from a query which should by pass the playground like below querystring:

**http://localhost:4000/demo?query=queryName()**

It is working fine with postman when i hit above url but when i am hitting on browser it is taking me on the apollo playground that should not happen

I have tried to disable the playground but it is not working for me

Please help me how i can directly get the query response from a url on the browser

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the below question

[Is there any option to disable playground when in production mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69614308/is-there-any-option-to-disable-playground-when-in-production-mode)

I have to configure apollo server like below:

```
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground,
         ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled } from 'apollo-server-core';
new ApolloServer({
  plugins: [
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled()
      : ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(),
  ],
});
```